What is the thread angle of the The 30°/3° German "Sägegewinde" (saw tooth) buttress thread form
On the wiki page about thread angle I saw that the thread angle for the German buttress threads is $\beta =30^\circ $.
But shouldn't it be $2\beta =30^\circ $ and that $\beta =15^\circ $?
On the other hand in the book Decker Maschinenelemente I saw that they wrote that $\beta =3^\circ $.
Now I am confused what is the correct thread angle $\beta$.
Also, for the metric trapezoidal threads I saw on the same wiki page that $\beta =30^\circ $, but shouldn't it be $2\beta =30^\circ $ and that $\beta =15^\circ $?
Here is the picture of the German buttress thread.

I am actually interested in knowing the $\beta$ because I want to calculate the torque I have in my spindle.
I am using the equation
$$T=F\left(\frac{d_2}{2}tg(\alpha+\rho')\right)\tag1$$
where $$\alpha=arctg\left(\frac{P_h}{d_2\pi}\right)\tag2$$
and
$$\rho'=arctg\left(\frac{\mu}{cos(\beta)}\right)\tag3$$.
And that angle $\beta$ is what I have to know.
I heard that it is being regarded to as the "working angle of the thread", but now I am not sure if that is the same as the "thread angle"?
The equations $(1)-(3)$ I am taking from my lecture notes, but I am having trouble finding them anywhere on the net, does someone have any references as from where I can find them and learn more about them?

Add the diagram as links can fail and wiki pages can be changed.

On the linked page there is no reference to $\beta$ as far as I can see.
